# Using PL/SQL Analytics to Count on Substring?

Tags: sql, plsql, substring, analytics, oracle12c

How should I write query to return a count of **3** for Farms Beginning with **K**?

Why does `(partition by id,substr(farm,1))` calculate to 1

```
with tree_harvest
as ( 
select 1 as id, 'PINE' as tree, 'K001' as farm from dual union all
select 1 as id, 'PINE' as tree, '0003' as farm from dual union all
select 1 as id, 'PINE' as tree, 'K002' as farm from dual union all
select 1 as id, 'PINE' as tree, 'K003' as farm from dual
)
select id, tree,farm,
       count(*) over (partition by id) as id_count,
       case
       when regexp_like(farm,'^K','i') 
       then count(*) over (partition by id,substr(farm,1))
       else 0
       end as k_count
       from tree_harvest;
```

**Desired Result**

```
 ID TREE FARM   ID_COUNT  K_COUNT  
  1 PINE  0003  4         0
  1 PINE  K001  4         3
  1 PINE  K002  4         3
  1 PINE  K003  4         3
```

Comment: So, what's the requirement? Return the input data, with one column added, where you show the K_COUNT on the rows where the FARM name begins with K, and 0 otherwise? (And, it seems from your attempt, the matching K should be case insensitive?) Why are you partitioning by ID - is that part of the requirement? And if it is, why isn't that stated in your "English" part of the question? In any case, your counts return 1 because SUBSTR(..., 1) just means the entire string. 1 as the second argument means "from which position" - you probably want SUBSTR(..., 1, 1) - the **second** 1 means length.

Comment: Requirement: If Farm begins with Letter K, the add it to K_count. There are three records where Farm begins with the Letter K. So I want K_count to calculate to 3 not 1.

Comment: Substr(...1,1) is the solution.. Thanks

Comment: If `substr(..., 1, 1)` solves your problem, then it's inefficient. Even if you must partition by id (which again you did not include in your "Requirement" in the comment above), you shouldn't further partition by `substr(.....)`. Instead, you should use a conditional count: `count (case when ... then 1 end) over (partition by id)` is more efficient than your current approach.

Comment: I'm partitioning by ID b/c I want to capture Farm counts at each ID. It's part of the requirement. It is case insensitive so Farms beginning with K or k are the same.

Comment: In your approach, you are still comparing the first character of `FARM` to `K` (case sensitive!) I will post a Reply showing the more efficient way you can do the same thing.

Comment: @mathguy:  Yes, I see how 'count (case when ...) '  generates what I'm really wanting for output. Each row populates for the true K_count: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f01bf/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that fixes your issue, and should be faster (more efficient) than your current approach. Note that here both analytic functions partition by `id` only; the conditional count is taken care separately, within the `count()` call itself. Also both comparisons to K or k are case insensitive; in your attempted query one of the comparisons wasn't. I also avoid regular expressions (slower), which are not needed here.

```
with tree_harvest
as ( 
select 1 as id, 'PINE' as tree, 'K001' as farm from dual union all
select 1 as id, 'PINE' as tree, '0003' as farm from dual union all
select 1 as id, 'PINE' as tree, 'K002' as farm from dual union all
select 1 as id, 'PINE' as tree, 'K003' as farm from dual
)
select id, tree,farm,
       count(*) over (partition by id) as id_count,
       case when lower(farm) like 'k%' then
           count(case when lower(farm) like 'k%' then 1 end) 
                over (partition by id) else 0 end as k_count
       from tree_harvest;
       
        ID TREE FARM   ID_COUNT    K_COUNT
---------- ---- ---- ---------- ----------
         1 PINE K001          4          3
         1 PINE K003          4          3
         1 PINE K002          4          3
         1 PINE 0003          4          0
```